# If $\gamma$ is a smooth complex-valued function, then why is it uniformly continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, bounded-variation

I have some confusions in the proof of the following theorem.

> If $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$, for $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$, is piecewise smooth then $\gamma$ is of bounded variation and its total variation is given by $$V(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}|\gamma'(t)|\,dt.$$

In the proof, the author argues as follows

[image]
[image]

---

**My Questions:**

- In the second equality, he uses the Fundamental Theorem to write $\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})=\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k}\gamma'(t)\,dt$. But **why is this true for complex-valued functions** $\gamma$ ? The author didn't prove any analog of the FTC for complex functions (yet). Does this follow for some other reasons?
- In the second paragraph, **why does $\gamma'$ being continuous imply that $\gamma'$ is uniformly continuous?** I thought this was, in general, only true for the converse.

---

The rest of the proof makes sense to me except these two arguments. TIA.

Comment: Isn't it because the domain is compact?

Comment: @Randall : I am aware of the result from Real Analysis you are referring to. But does it hold for complex-valued functions as well?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember.

Comment: It is a result of metric space analysis... we don't need smoothness, just continuity and compactness of domain

Comment: @FShrike : Can you point me to a reference of such a result?

Comment: @Randall : Also, what about the FTC? Does that also hold for complex-valued functions?

Comment: [Royden's real analysis](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf), pdf page 213

Comment: @FShrike : Got it thanks;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The FTC is true for complex, and more generally $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued functions because you can apply the usual FTC to each component function.
2. $\gamma'$ is a continuous function on a compact set. Uniform continuity is a consequence. See proposition 3.1.4 on page 90 of
   http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf